# notifyDataSetChanged method not working with BaseAdapter and ListView

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I m using the base adapter with `listview` to display students picture with their name in my project. It's OK. But after that, I am using a Handler to update the picture dynamically when a student changes the picture from their apps. it is not working as desired.

The base adapter is getting data (`ArrayList`) from local **SQLite** DB and the **SQLite** is getting data from the server by AsyncTask in the handler. The first time it's displaying all the student's image and name very well but image update dynamically not working.

I am using `notifyDataSetChanged` method whenever the adapter's underlying data changes. I've tried `SimpleAdapter`, `ArrayAdapter` also but the problem persists. what should I do???

Comment: Please add code snippet you have tried for help

Answer (score 0):

You have used `notifyDataSetChanged` method for `Base-adapter` and `Array Adapter` But This method works like ,if  your Adapter's data changed then it will update your View according to data. but if you update data inside database then it will not get any change and your view is not update so you need to reset your `adapter` for it.

Comment: actually i am using a method everytime where adapter's referenced data is totally newly formed from database cursor after a data.clear(). everything is going perfect (I've checked by database query just before listview refresh) but notifyDatasetChanged() not refreshing the listview.